# Let anyone view Firebase app

Tags: firebase

In order to demonstrate Firebase I'd like to make the back-end of my Firebase app viewable to the general public, similar to [Firebase's Tetris example](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/tetris) except read-only. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly. Instead, you can make a page that visualizes the data for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Firebase visualizer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.9/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
    var url = "https://[YOUR-FIREBASE-APP].firebaseio.com";
    window.onload = function(){
      var firebase = new Firebase(url);
      var output = document.getElementById("output");
      var link = document.getElementById("link");
      var data;

      link.href = url;
      link.innerHTML = url;

      firebase.child("/").on("value", function(response){
        output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.val(), null, 2);
      });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>The content of <a id="link" target="_blank"></a>.</p> 
    <pre id="output">

    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```